# Electrical lug for button switch

Tags: crimp

So I bought a few push buttons that came with lugs but I'm not sure what tool I am supposed to use crimp them to wire. Advice is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You would use a terminal crimper. You didn't bother to mention any model numbers for the parts you have, so I won't bother to find you a crimper model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

The loop in the wire keeps it from pulling out.

You can even fold the wire more than once.

Use the end of a screwdriver blade to fold the ears over the wire.

Crimp down using pliers.

Note: solid wire will not withstand continued stress from being moved repeatedly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crimping tools like [this one](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ats/ATS-638111000.pdf) are used for this. They are usually quite expensive, though.

The exact model of crimping tool depends on the dimensions of your contacts. Note that most contacts like the one on the photo are designed for stranded wire.

If this is one-off project and you want to use solid wire you can try carefully soldering it taking care the solder does not flow into contacts. Then use pliers to squeeze larger "ears" around the insulation. This would be sub-optimal solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect to "unplug" the switch from the wires frequently, I would just solder to the switch terminals.

I have occasionally crimped similar terminals with small-nosed pliers, bending in the sides one at a time - this is OK (but far from optimal) with stranded wire, but I wouldn't do it with solid wire unless I also soldered the joint.